# Subsetting a Vector in R with a numeric

Tags: r

I'm trying to better understand indexing/subsetting behaviour.

Consider the numeric vector `x`:

```
x <- c(1.0, 2.0)
```

I can get at its values:

```
x[1L] # the first element of a 1-indexed vector
#> [1] 1
x[2L] # the second element of a 1-indexed vector
#> [1] 2
x[3L] # the third element, which is not defined/ does not exists, so returns `NA`; ok.
#> [1] NA
```

But I'm confused by these returns:

```
x[1.1]
#> [1] 1
x[2.7]
#> [1] 2
x[3.1]
#> [1] NA
```

Moreover it seems this doesn't work like I would expect:

```
x[2.6] <- 3.0 
x
#> [1] 1 3
```

Can someone help me understand why this is?

Comment: This index is made into an integer.  So the index becomes `as.integer(2.7)` which is `2`

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why the decided to floor() the indices? It seems like it would be healthy to return an error if a non-integer numeric index was entered.

Comment: I don't really know why they wrote it like that, and I also don't know if `as.integer()` is even implemented because `[` is a primitive function so it goes straight to C code.  All I know is that that's how it works and it is what it is. ;)

Comment: Fair enough, I was just fishing for additional information about this unorthodox feature if you happened to know.

Comment: As the help page says: `Numeric values are coerced to integer as by as.integer (and hence truncated towards zero).`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the core issue was the I didn't know about:

```
?`[`
```

which as @BondedDust points out tells you:

> indices specifying elements to extract or replace. Indices are numeric or character vectors or empty (missing) or NULL. Numeric values are coerced to integer as by as.integer (and hence truncated towards zero). Character vectors will be matched to the names of the object (or for matrices/arrays, the dimnames): see ‘Character indices’ below for further details.

So it was just that the behaviour was defined this way.